# Usando VirtualFields em variavel cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Eu criei um virtual *field*, mas não tenho muito conceito sobre isso, até hoje só usei pra fazer paginação, como que faço pra usar o resultado desse virtual em uma variável?

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'js_dt_inicio' => '(CASE WHEN inicio_de IS NOT NULL AND inicio_de!=\'\' AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)<=inicio_de THEN inicio_de ELSE DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) END)',
);
```

Comment: você sabe pra que serve uma `virtualField`?

Comment: Criar um campo virtual com critérios sql em um modelo.

Comment: Portanto esse campo virtual será criado no retorno de uma consulta `sql`, para retornar o valor de campo virtual em uma variável você precisa fazer uma consulta que retorne o seu `virtualField`.

Comment: A minha dúvida é como montar esse consulta no controller..
`$this->Curso->find('js_dt_inicio')`;

Comment: `$this->ModelName->find("all");`  precisa dizer mais detalhes para te ajudar a montar esse `find()`, o que já fez?